# Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Native module RNDatePicker tried to override RNDatePicker - React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have deployed my app using eas build -p android but when I open the apk on my phone I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Native module RNDatePicker tried to override RNDatePicker. Check the getPackages() method in MainApplication.java, it might be that module is being created twice. If this was your intention, set canOverrideExistingModule=true. This error may also be present if the package is present only once in getPackages() but is also automatically added later during build time by autolinking. Try removing the existing entry and rebuild.
    at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:55)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1467)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1438)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1340)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.-$$Nest$mcreateReactContext(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

the app works well on development only in production the error happen

when I open my apk file the app closes inmediatly